# href not working with z-index -1

Tags: css

Helllo, I have this html code

```
<div class="tf">
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/!!!" target="_blank" ><img src="images/twitter.png" width="2%" class="tfimg"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/!!!/212810852094228" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png"  width="2%" class="tfimg"></a>
</div>
```

and for the CSS

```
   .tf {
float:right;
margin-right:65px;
margin-top:-30px;
padding:2px;
}

.tfimg {
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
border:none;
}
```

to be the image out of the border but I can't click in the image so what's the problem and what's the solution for that ?

Comment: Could you give me a litle bit more description please, cant quite make sense of what your trying to achive there...

Answer (score 1):

Both of your images have the same class assigned to them. You are stacking them on top of each other by not setting them to different positions and the facebook.com one appears on top since it is last in the html. If you want them to appear beside each other you can apply something like the following:

```
.tftwitter {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
border:none;
}

.tffacebook {
position:absolute;
left: 20px;
border:none;
}
```

And now assign each image the appropriate class.

Comment: Lol hes using the &nbsp; spaces to position the facebook image to the right

Answer (score 0):

try using:

`.tf{
   display:inline-block;
   /* your more code */
}`

Comment: like this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/6/tftf.jpg/ but if I did like this the z-index will be -1 and a href doesn't work so what is the solution ?